# Is there a more "functional programming" approach to solve this without using `forEach`?

Tags: javascript, foreach, functional-programming

I have heard it said that, with new (or at least better) JavaScript language options, we don't need to use `forEach` anymore. I wonder if this was an indirect way of advocating for functional programming. I have recently encountered an array manipulation algorithm that required the nested use of `forEach` and am wondering if there is a more functional way of approaching the problem. I was able to re-write the code using `reduce` but it ended up being longer than the `forEach` solution. In and of itself, slightly longer code might not be "bad", but this does make me wonder if there is perhaps an even better way to use functional programming to solve this problem.

The problem is as follows: re-work an array of arrays to produce a flattened array of all the original elements, but with each new element now paired with the number of the original sub-array it came from. e.g. Convert `[[8,2,4],[5],[1,7]]` into `[[8,0],[2,0],[4,0],[5,1],[1,2],[7,2]]`.

*(For readers to make sense of many of the initial critical comments to this question, the original wording of the question focused on making the code shorter. My true intention was instead to ask about a better way to approach this problem, leading to the re-worded question above.)*

```js
const oldArr = [[8,2,4],[5],[1,7]];

const newArr1 = [];
oldArr.forEach((subArr, subArrNum) => {
  subArr.forEach(elmt => {newArr1.push([elmt, subArrNum]);});
});

const newArr2 = oldArr.reduce((accum1, subArr, subArrNum) => accum1.concat(
  subArr.reduce((accum2, elmt) => accum2.concat([[elmt, subArrNum]]), [])
), []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr2));

// for the sake of comparing code length, here are the exact same two
// solutions using only single letter variable names with each solution
// compressed onto a single line:

const o = oldArr;
let x,y;

x=[];o.forEach((s,n)=>{s.forEach(e=>{x.push([e,n]);});});

y=o.reduce((a,s,n)=>a.concat(s.reduce((b,e)=>b.concat([[e,n]]),[])),[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: This seems like it could perhaps be better-received in the code golf subreddit? Maybe I'm just overfitting based on the "fewest characters" mention. I'm not going to vote to close, though.

Comment: Are you being charged for each keystroke? If this is simple curiosity, it's hardly going to be helpful for the wider SO community and future searchers. And, since I'm not feeling as magnanimous as furkle, I *am* voting to close :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo The question as framed looks like a simple curiosity. However, it could definitely be helpful for the wider SO community if it does in fact uncover a more space-efficient way of solving a particular subset of array-manipulation problems, especially in cases where the real problem at hand, rather than this admittedly simple one, _is_ significantly longer and thus saving "a few keystrokes" here and there adds up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs (if anywhere) on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: number of keystrokes are not, ever, a factor in real world programming. Nice question for reddit, not a question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Andrew, if it was looking for a more space-efficient way (in terms of space taken by the running program, i.e., space complexity), I'd welcome it with open arms. Space efficiency for the source code (especially when it's this small) seems of dubious use to me. Still, I'm only one of the swarm, if enough people think otherwise, they can annul/reverse any close decision...

Comment: `[].concat(...o.map((x,i)=>x.map(y=>[y,i])))` FWIW

Comment: I think a loop that go over all the element is necessary, hence the use of a loop or foreach is necessary. This is not like a search algorithm that could be optimised. This have to go through each array item by item.

Comment: A reasonable analogy is the use of `for...of` loops. These are a completely valid approach to solving many array-manipulation problems, but have been superceded as the optimal approach for some of those question since new JavaScript functionality has been introduced. I _want_ to learn about those new more efficient approaches, and I believe that other SO readers would as well.

Comment: @AndrewWillems - space-efficient != fewest keystrokes

Comment: @Ryan... _THAT_ is exactly what I was looking for! Could you please post that as an answer before this is closed?

Comment: @Ted Hopp, the use of "space-efficient" as a tag for this question was simply a way of selecting one of the available SO tag options that most concisely said "this question is about reducing the length of the code"...and that tag had no description connected to it, so I thought it was fair game.

Comment: In programming. _space efficiency_ almost always refers to how much memory an algorithm uses. Sometimes it refers to how efficient a particular data structure is (theoretical minimum amount of memory needed divided by memory actually required).

Comment: In response to all the votes to close, @Ryan's answer has definitely already helped me to become a better programmer by revealing a new use of `map` to apply to a particular problem, and a potentially better way of thinking. This question isn't about, say, reducing code length by just shortening variable names or eliminating spaces. It's about learning about a more efficient way to use the language, space-wise but also (and importantly) in terms of logic.

Comment: @TedHopp, thank you for the clarification about the meaning of "space efficiency". It would be great if you could input that as a description for the SO tag, as it currently has no description/explanation.

Comment: Oh, so you’re wondering about using a more functional style to manipulate data vs. `forEach`’s imperative? That makes more sense. (If that is the case, you might want to focus on that more than keystrokes in the question. They’re not very meaningful in JavaScript, where hacks like `[].concat(...x)` are shortest due to lack of builtins.)

Comment: @Ryan, sure. I'm asking about how to write shorter code as a way to ask about writing better code, whether that's related to learning about functional programming (which I am learning to embrace whole-heartedly but is still "new" to me) or whatever. But thanks for understanding that I'm not _simply_ asking "How do I make my code shorter?" On that note, in retrospect, I wonder whether the comment that I heard about `forEach` no longer being necessary was a tangential way of saying "Embrace functional programming!"

Comment: slightly longer, but pre-babel safe:

    `const newArray = [].concat.apply([],a.map((b,k)=>(b.map(v=>[v,k]))))`

As your comment states you don't care so much about extreme brevity I suggest writing it in the most readable way you can rather than spending any time compacting your code. we have compilers for that.

Comment: @Ryan, are you saying `[].concat(...x)` is a code smell?

Comment: @AndrewWillems: Yes. It can cause a stack overflow, for one; try `[].concat(...Array(1000000))`. Ideally there would be a builtin along the lines of `const concat = arrs => arrs.reduce((m, n) => m.concat(n), []);` (but maybe more efficient).

Comment: @Ryan, I would not have spotted the problem with `[].concat(...x)`. Thanks very much for that. On that same note, is there any code smell in the `reduce`-using approach I proposed in the question, i.e. `o.reduce((a,s,n)=>a.concat(s.reduce((b,e)=>b.concat([[e,n]]),[])),[])`?

Comment: Generally you’d separate it into map and reduce steps for easier reading (which is what I did, only with a spread instead of reduce to save characters), but it’s not terrible. =)

Comment: @TedHopp, after reading [an overview of the CodeReview site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102869) I agree that that would have been a better place for this question. However, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250) states that questions already answered should not be migrated. I've already answered this question based on other comments. I also took the criticisms from you and others to heart and significantly edited the question to focus on using more understandable functional programming rather than just trying to get shorter code. Any chance you might vote to re-open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments on the question, @Ryan provided a solution, labelled as `newArray1` in the code below, while @Potter provided a "babel-safe" variant, labelled as `newArray2` (with minor changes in variable names and removal of parentheses to make the two functions more easily comparable):

```js
const o = [[8,2,4],[5],[1,7]];

const newArray1 = [].concat      (   ...o.map((x,i)=>x.map(y=>[y,i])));
const newArray2 = [].concat.apply([],   o.map((x,i)=>x.map(y=>[y,i])));

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray2));
```

I think the reduction of clutter in this solution makes it slightly easier to understand than my original functional solution.

Note, however, that Ryan also points out in a further comment on the question a problem with this approach. He writes that `[].concat(...x)` (and, I presume, also its "babel-safe" variant) "...can cause a stack overflow, for one; try `[].concat(...Array(1000000))`. Ideally there would be a builtin along the lines of `const concat = arrs => arrs.reduce((m, n) => m.concat(n), []);` (but maybe more efficient)."